# Two lines duplicate in an MS Word 2007 table, cannot be deleted

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I've got a table in an MS Word 2007 document in which the first two lines (not the heading line) are duplicated closer to the end, for an unknown reason.
I cannot select them using the mouse. O_O

What can I do to delete them?

I added a comment to the author by selecting one of the lines and adding a comment (because the "original" line can be selected and edited). Strangely, the comment duplicated closer to the end, where this line duplicates.

I'm translating this document and it's the author's business really to deal this bugs of this sort, but I'm curious.

P.S. I selected the whole table and copied it into another document, and voila, the repeating lines vanished. The repearing lines were just under where the table crossed a border between two pages.

P.P.S. However, when I return the "healthy" table into the original document, the two duplicate lines just below the page border appear again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line may be marked as 'repeat this line on each page'?

Select the line, right-click into it, and look in the format for that option. You need to check the first of the duplicates, not the second.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, both lines have the "repeat this line" option enabled, but it is greyed out, so I cannot tick it off. It's locked. The heading has this option enabled too, but it's not locked. That's odd.

Comment: I transferred the data into newly-created lines and deleted those doomed lines. Case closed.